# Shared Clipboard is not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, virtualbox

I have VirtualBox installed and shared-clipboard is enabled as bi-directional.

But it does not work at all.

How can I get it working?

Comment: Do you have the VirtualBox Add-ons installed inside the VM?

Comment: I dont know. How do I check?

Comment: Andreas means Virtualbox Guest Additions.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  @MariaMeh: Depends on your guest operating system.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed inside that. Once it was working. It did not when I re-installed the Ubuntu 12.04 inside VirtualBox

Comment: What's your host os?

Comment: Windows 8 64-bit...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First install virtual box guest addition by mounting the VirtualBoxguestAddition.iso file.It was actually resides inside `c:/Program Files/oracle/virtualbox` folder.
- In Windows 8, guestadditions.iso file will be automatically mounted when you double click on that iso file.
- After it got mounted, it automatically prompts you install guest additions in the host OS.
- Then install the guest Additions in the guest OS(Ubuntu).
- Because of you're running Ubuntu as guest OS, you have to run the below commands on terminal,

  ```
  $ killall VBoxClient
  $ VBoxClient-all
  ```
- Now you can be able to use shared clipboard option.