# VirtualBox Shared Clipboard issue

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, fedora

Consider the following scenario.

**VirtualBox**: version 6.0.8 r130520 (Qt5.6.2).

**Host**: Windows 10, Extension Pack installed latest version.

**Guest**: Fedora 30, Guest Additions installed latest version from Oracle iso (*Devices -> insert guest additions cd image*). No errors in the logs. Configured *Shared clipboard -> Bidirectional* from VirtualBox GUI for this virtual machine, then reboot both guest and host.

Here is the configuration file for this virtual machine:

```
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.16-windows">
  <Machine uuid="{3e996267-1e33-494a-9f6c-c3164d08b94c}" name="Jenkins_Fedora" OSType="Fedora_64" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2019-05-22T07:21:58Z">
    <MediaRegistry>
      <HardDisks>
        <HardDisk uuid="{2f31a2ba-2873-4997-a15c-0ce0dd8bddfa}" location="Jenkins_Fedora.vdi" format="VDI" type="Normal"/>
      </HardDisks>
      <DVDImages>
        <Image uuid="{0243ea34-50c9-47b2-aa1c-297ff5ef1366}" location="C:/Users/gmart/Downloads/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-30-1.2.iso"/>
      </DVDImages>
    </MediaRegistry>
    <ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastCloseAction" value="Shutdown"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastGuestSizeHint" value="928,825"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition" value="-975,344,928,864"/>
    </ExtraData>
    <Hardware>
      <CPU>
        <PAE enabled="false"/>
        <LongMode enabled="true"/>
        <X2APIC enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="true"/>
      </CPU>
      <Memory RAMSize="2048"/>
      <HID Pointing="USBTablet"/>
      <Boot>
        <Order position="1" device="DVD"/>
        <Order position="2" device="HardDisk"/>
        <Order position="3" device="None"/>
        <Order position="4" device="None"/>
      </Boot>
      <Display VRAMSize="16"/>
      <VideoCapture screens="1" file="." fps="25"/>
      <BIOS>
        <IOAPIC enabled="true"/>
      </BIOS>
      <USB>
        <Controllers>
          <Controller name="OHCI" type="OHCI"/>
          <Controller name="EHCI" type="EHCI"/>
        </Controllers>
      </USB>
      <Network>
        <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027CFACC8" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <InternalNetwork name="intnet"/>
            <NATNetwork name="NatNetwork"/>
          </DisabledModes>
          <BridgedInterface name="Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller"/>
        </Adapter>
      </Network>
      <AudioAdapter codec="AD1980" driver="DirectSound" enabled="true" enabledIn="false"/>
      <RTC localOrUTC="UTC"/>
      <Clipboard mode="Bidirectional"/>
      <DragAndDrop mode="Bidirectional"/>
      <GuestProperties>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/HostVerLastChecked" value="6.0.8" timestamp="1557904292112982500" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Revision" value="129722" timestamp="1557902352754733400" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Version" value="6.0.6" timestamp="1557902352753750500" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VersionExt" value="6.0.6_Fedora" timestamp="1557902352753750501" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Product" value="Linux" timestamp="1557902352750842800" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Release" value="5.0.14-300.fc30.x86_64" timestamp="1557902352750842801" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Version" value="#1 SMP Thu May 9 10:43:38 UTC 2019" timestamp="1557902352751798500" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID" value="en_US" timestamp="1558510562696428200" flags="RDONLYGUEST"/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxRev" value="130520" timestamp="1558509718922840802" flags="TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST"/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxVer" value="6.0.8" timestamp="1558509718922840800" flags="TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST"/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxVerExt" value="6.0.8" timestamp="1558509718922840801" flags="TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST"/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/VMInfo/ResetCounter" value="1" timestamp="1558510356442820700" flags="TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST"/>
      </GuestProperties>
    </Hardware>
    <StorageControllers>
      <StorageController name="IDE" type="PIIX4" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true">
        <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" hotpluggable="false" port="1" device="0"/>
      </StorageController>
      <StorageController name="SATA" type="AHCI" PortCount="1" useHostIOCache="false" Bootable="true" IDE0MasterEmulationPort="0" IDE0SlaveEmulationPort="1" IDE1MasterEmulationPort="2" IDE1SlaveEmulationPort="3">
        <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" hotpluggable="false" port="0" device="0">
          <Image uuid="{2f31a2ba-2873-4997-a15c-0ce0dd8bddfa}"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
      </StorageController>
    </StorageControllers>
  </Machine>
</VirtualBox>
```

**The question:** Copy and paste is not working (greyed option in right-click menu), both from host to guest and from guest to host.

The following Q/A does not resolved in my case:

- [VirtualBox - shared clipboard not working](https://superuser.com/questions/924913/virtualbox-shared-clipboard-not-working)
- [Virtualbox clipboard not working](https://superuser.com/questions/1077970/virtualbox-clipboard-not-working)
- [Shared Clipboard is not working](https://superuser.com/questions/735404/shared-clipboard-is-not-working)
- [How do I enable the shared clipboard in VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/42134/how-do-i-enable-the-shared-clipboard-in-virtualbox)
- [Bidirectional clipboard not working in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/1293042/bidirectional-clipboard-not-working-in-virtualbox)

What I'm missing? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you.

Updating kernel resolved the issue in my case.

```
> uname -r
5.1.5-300.fc30.x86_64
```

Removing and installing Guest Additions from other source was not required.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer precisely on what is missing but can say how to get it working.

Having no problems with other guests, for Fedora 30 I got it working by:

- remove Guest Additions previously installed from original ISO

  `/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-6.0.8/uninstall.sh`
- install them from rpm

  `dnf install virtualbox-guest-additions`

Comment: thank you, updating kernel resolved in my case without removing and re-installing guest additions